# Why can a for loop in Rust iterate over a slice or iterator, but not an array?

Tags: arrays, vector, rust, iterator, slice

Why can a `for` loop in Rust 1.44.0 iterate over a slice or iterator, but not an array?  For example, the following threw me for a loop:

Loop over an array:

```
fn main() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    for element in a {
        println!("element={}", element);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0277]: `[{integer}; 5]` is not an iterator
 --> main.rs:4:20
  |
4 |     for element in a {
  |                    ^ borrow the array with `&` or call `.iter()` on it to iterate over it
  |
  = help: the trait `std::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for `[{integer}; 5]`
  = note: arrays are not iterators, but slices like the following are: `&[1, 2, 3]`
  = note: required by `std::iter::IntoIterator::into_iter`
```

Loop over a slice (version 1):

```
fn main() {
    let a = &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    for element in a {
        println!("element={}", element);
    }
}
```

```
element=1
element=2
element=3
element=4
element=5
```

Loop over a slice (version 2):

```
fn main() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    for element in &a {
        println!("element={}", element);
    }
}
```

```
element=1
element=2
element=3
element=4
element=5
```

Loop over an array iterator:

```
fn main() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    for element in a.iter() {
        println!("element={}", element);
    }
}
```

```
element=1
element=2
element=3
element=4
element=5
```

Rust can also loop in this way over a vector:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    for element in v {
        println!("element={}", element);
    }
}
```

```
element=1
element=2
element=3
element=4
element=5
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The compiler tells you why: because arrays are not iterators.

There is [a long standing issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25725) to implement `IntoIterator` for arrays, unfortunately, adding this would be a breaking change and there are known issues in the ecosystem with “just doing it”, so progress is slow on this matter.

As of Rust 1.51, you can use [`array::IntoIter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/array/struct.IntoIter.html):

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    for element in std::array::IntoIter::new(a) {
        println!("element={}", element);
    }
}
```

[As of Rust 1.53](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/06/17/Rust-1.53.0.html#intoiterator-for-arrays), you can use [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html), but as a special case, the compiler will continue to resolve `array.into_iter()` as `(&array).into_iter()` for backward compatibility. This includes the `for`-loop desugaring.

[As of Edition 2021](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/05/11/edition-2021.html#intoiterator-for-arrays), the special case has been removed, and array iteration works as any other type.

Comment: So does an array slice implement `IntoIterator`?  How does this work?

Comment: How does "borrowing" array `a` turn it into an iterator?

Comment: @Derek The same way as for any other type: [there's an implementation of `IntoIterator` for `&[T]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#impl-IntoIterator-1).

Answer (score 11):

Starting from Rust 1.53.0, the behavior of iteration for `array` has changed. Now we can iterate over arrays by value:

```
for i in [1, 2, 3] {
    ...
}
```

The code is legal now. See more at [Announcing Rust 1.53.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/06/17/Rust-1.53.0.html).

Comment: This is good news!  This change finally makes iteration of Rust arrays match that of vectors.